# Calling a program from another program in Java

Tags: java, user-interface, instance

I've been learning how to create a text editor in Java (new to Java) and **I'd like to include a button that lets the user to create a new text file in a separate window**, just like how you can create a new text file in notepad or TextEdit. But I'm not sure how one does this?

So far I've created an Action for the "New file" option and **I'd like this option to open another text editor window simply by clicking a button in the first text editor**. That's what I'm stuck on. I read that using a ProcessBuilder is the way to go, but I don't think I'm using it correctly (see the code block in the Action named "New").

More generally I'd like to call a program from another program that's already running, just in this case they both belong to the same class.

EDIT: I'm not referring to saving a file using IO streams. I'm **just** stuck on how to call a program from another program that's already running, and I want to call another program by literally clicking a button on the GUI.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.text.DefaultEditorKit;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;

public class textEditor {
    private JFrame window = new JFrame("Text editor");
    private JTextArea area = new JTextArea();
    private JFileChooser dialog = new JFileChooser(System.getProperty("user.dir")); // user.dir gets user's working directory
    private String currentFile = "Untitled";
    private boolean changed = false;

    public static int numPrograms = 1;

    public static void main(String[] args){
        textEditor tester = new textEditor();

    }

    public textEditor(){
        // Set up JFrame
        window.setTitle(currentFile);
        window.setSize(500, 600);
        window.setVisible(true);
        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);


        // Set up the text editing area
        area.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.PLAIN, 16));
        area.setLineWrap(true);
        area.setWrapStyleWord(true);
        JScrollPane jsp = new JScrollPane(area);
        window.add(jsp, BorderLayout.CENTER);


        // Menu bar
        JMenuBar JMB = new JMenuBar();
        window.setJMenuBar(JMB);
        JMenu file = new JMenu("File");
        JMenu edit = new JMenu("Edit");

        JMB.add(file);
        JMB.add(edit);

        file.add(New);      // TODO add the New action to the file menu
        file.add(Open);
        file.add(Save);
        file.add(SaveAs);
        file.addSeparator();
        file.add(Exit);

        // Stops the user from trying to save the text that's exactly the same as that
        Save.setEnabled(false);
        SaveAs.setEnabled(false);

        // Stops the images specified in the Actions from showing up in the file menu
        for(int i=0; i<3; i++)
            file.getItem(i).setIcon(null);
        file.getItem(4).setIcon(null);

        edit.add(Cut);
        edit.add(Copy);
        edit.add(Paste);

        edit.getItem(0).setText("Cut");
        edit.getItem(1).setText("Copy");
        edit.getItem(2).setText("Paste");

        // Toolbar
        JToolBar tool = new JToolBar();
        tool.setFloatable(false);   // Prevents the user from being able to take out the toolbar as a separate window
        window.add(tool, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        //tool.add(New);
        tool.add(Open);
        tool.add(Save);
        tool.addSeparator();


        // Adds cut, copy and paste buttons to the JToolBar
        JButton cut = tool.add(Cut), cop = tool.add(Copy), pas = tool.add(Paste);
        cut.setText(null); cut.setIcon(new ImageIcon("cut.gif"));
        cop.setText(null); cop.setIcon(new ImageIcon("copy.gif"));
        pas.setText(null); pas.setIcon(new ImageIcon("paste.gif"));

        area.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
            @Override
            // If a key is pressed, allow the user to save the document and note that the document has changed
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
                changed = true;
                Save.setEnabled(true);
                SaveAs.setEnabled(true);
            }
        });
    }

    private void saveFileAs() {
        if(dialog.showSaveDialog(null)==JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)
            saveFile(dialog.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath());
    }

    private int saveOld() {
        int saveOldNum = JOptionPane.CANCEL_OPTION;

        if(changed) {
            saveOldNum = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(window, "Would you like to save "+ currentFile +" ?",
                    "Save", JOptionPane.YES_NO_CANCEL_OPTION);
            if(saveOldNum == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION)
                if(currentFile.equals("Untitled"))
                    saveFileAs();
                else
                    saveFile(currentFile);
        }

        return saveOldNum;
    }


    private void readInFile(String fileName) {
        try {
            FileReader r = new FileReader(fileName);
            area.read(r,null);  // loads in data as plain text
            r.close();
            currentFile = fileName;
            window.setTitle(currentFile);
            changed = false;
        }
        catch(IOException e) {
            Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().beep();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(window,"Editor can't find the file called " + fileName);
        }
    }

    private void saveFile(String fileName) {
        try {
            FileWriter w = new FileWriter(fileName);
            area.write(w);      // stores only plain text
            w.close();
            currentFile = fileName;
            window.setTitle(currentFile);
            changed = false;
            Save.setEnabled(false);
        }
        catch(IOException e) {
            Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().beep();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(window, "Cannot save file to " + fileName);
        }
    }



    // ACTIONS

    // New
    Action New = new AbstractAction() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if(saveOld() != JOptionPane.CANCEL_OPTION){
                Process process = new ProcessBuilder("textEditor.java").start();
            }
        }
    };


    // Open
    Action Open = new AbstractAction("Open", new ImageIcon("open.gif")) {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if(saveOld() != JOptionPane.CANCEL_OPTION && dialog.showOpenDialog(null)==JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)
                readInFile(dialog.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath());
            SaveAs.setEnabled(true);
        }
    };


    // Save
    Action Save = new AbstractAction("Save", new ImageIcon("save.gif")) {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if(currentFile.equals("Untitled"))
                saveFileAs();
            else
                saveFile(currentFile);
        }
    };


    // Save as
    Action SaveAs = new AbstractAction("Save as...") {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            saveFileAs();
        }
    };


    // Exit
    Action Exit = new AbstractAction("Exit") {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if(saveOld() != JOptionPane.CANCEL_OPTION)
                System.exit(0);
        }
    };


    ActionMap m = area.getActionMap();
    Action Cut = m.get(DefaultEditorKit.cutAction);
    Action Copy = m.get(DefaultEditorKit.copyAction);
    Action Paste = m.get(DefaultEditorKit.pasteAction);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is your answer but next time you need to explain more like what you want us to do it's not just a help build my code for me session.
Hopefully this helps any other help needed try here they have great help on Java.
**http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-write-to-file-in-java-bufferedwriter-example/**

```
package com.mkyong;

import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;

public class WriteToFileExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {

            String content = "This is the content to write into file";

            File file = new File("/users/mkyong/filename.txt");

            // if file doesnt exists, then create it
            if (!file.exists()) {
                file.createNewFile();
            }

            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile());
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
            bw.write(content);
            bw.close();

            System.out.println("Done");

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this but I just want to call a program from another program that's already running simply by clicking a button. I have edited my question for better clarification.

Comment: You can still convert that into it